# Not able to open components in CME after the Web 8 upgrade

Tags: web8, upgrade

We installed web 8 and restored DB backup from 2013 SP1.
When I try to open a component a new tab appears, the URL comes but the web 8 icon keeps spinning up and I don't see any data.
The CME also shows that the component has been checked out and after closing the tab I have to explicitly check in the component.
We are able to open everything else. We have disabled our custom functionality as well.
Anyone had this issue after the upgrade or can suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have Custom GUI Extensions installed that work on ComponentView? If you are using Chrome, open the developer console and check to see if there are any JavaScript errors. From the looks of it, seems like some GUI Extension is broken post upgrade causing the system to halt at the loading screen.

Comment: Did you upgrade the database after restoring?

Comment: @Kunal: All the GUI extension are disabled.

Comment: @Bart: yeah the DB was upgrade to 8.1.1

Comment: Try to open item from Parent publication, see if works also it is issue in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. It is due to one of our custom GUI extension. I disabled the extension and I am able to open components now.
I will update more once I fix the extension issue.

Comment: i think Kunal above answered it so he should actually move his comment to answer and you accept it

Comment: I agree Raj Kumar. Kunal gave me the clue and I would be happy to accept his answer. Kunal please move your comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have any legacy building block like vbscript templates in your existing 2013 SP1 CMS. if this is the case, either delete them/upgrade them or install your Web 8 with legacy support.

If this is not the case, illogical solutions sometime works - Try unistalling and installing the Web 8 (don't forget you are running the installer by choosing "Run As Administrator")

I hope this may help

Comment: but he has issue in component opening only, how  can vbscripts templates cause it?